# Can't Install Magento : Blank page - Magento 1.8

Tags: magento-1.8, installation

I try to install Magento **1.8.0**, but when i load install page i get:

> Firefox: blank page
>
> Chrome: This page isn’t working localhost is currently unable to
>        handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Please can you help me to resolve this problem

**Work Environment :**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- php 5.6
- nginx 1.10.0
- mysql 5.7.18

Info can be useful: I tried to debug **index.php** and i discover that index file can't include `/app/mag.php`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know magento 1.8.x doesn't support php 5.6 and mysql 5.7, but blank page told that you have problems with your environment.

A suggestion:

1. Try to install latest 1.9.3.3. If all is well, then  problem in support version of LAMP stack

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried with magento 1.9.3.3 & i get the same problem. Also in ubuntu 16.04 php version is 7.0 and we can downgrade until 5.6.